# @SpringBootTest UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have this IntegrationTestBase abstract class:

```java
package personal.tunelink;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.TestPropertySourceUtils;
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer;

@ActiveProfiles("itest")
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = IntegrationTestBase.ContextInitializer.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public abstract class IntegrationTestBase {

    private static final PostgreSQLContainer postgresTestContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:15")
            .withUsername("itest")
            .withPassword("itest")
            .withDatabaseName("tunelink");

    static {
        postgresTestContainer.start();
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class ContextInitializer implements
            ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
            final String url = postgresTestContainer.getJdbcUrl();
            final String username = postgresTestContainer.getUsername();
            final String password = postgresTestContainer.getPassword();
            TestPropertySourceUtils.addInlinedPropertiesToEnvironment(
                    configurableApplicationContext,
                    "spring.datasource.url=" + url,
                    "spring.datasource.username=" + username,
                    "spring.datasource.password=" + password
            );
        }
    }
}
```

My build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'jvm-test-suite'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group 'tunelink'
version '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:3.1.5'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'


    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.5'
    runtimeOnly 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.11.5'
    runtimeOnly 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.11.5'

    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.5.1'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation "org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.17.6"
    testImplementation "org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:1.17.6"
    testImplementation "org.testcontainers:postgresql:1.17.6"
}

sourceSets {
    testcommons{
        java{
            srcDir 'src/testcommons/java'
            compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
            runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        }
    }
}

testing {
    suites {
        test {
            useJUnitJupiter()

            dependencies {
                implementation(sourceSets["testcommons"].output)
            }
        }

        itest(JvmTestSuite) {
            testType = TestSuiteType.INTEGRATION_TEST

            dependencies {
                implementation project()
                implementation(sourceSets["testcommons"].output)
            }

            configurations {
                itestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
                itestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
                itestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom testRuntimeOnly
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Repository test class:

```java
package personal.tunelink.user;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import perosnal.tunelink.user.UserRepository;
import personal.tunelink.IntegrationTestBase;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

public class UserRepositoryITest extends IntegrationTestBase {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    void test() {
        assertNotNull(userRepository);
    }
}
```

Repository class:

```java
package perosnal.tunelink.user;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM user u " +
            "JOIN user_top_tracks utt ON u.id = utt.user_id " +
            "WHERE u.id =?1", nativeQuery = true)
    User getById(String id);


    @Query(value = "SELECT * from user where id IN (" +
            "SELECT that.user_id " +
            "FROM user_top_tracks AS this INNER JOIN user_top_tracks " +
            "AS that ON that.user_id <> this.user_id " +
            "AND that.track_id = this.track_id WHERE this.user_id = ?1 " +
            "GROUP BY that.user_id HAVING COUNT(*) >= ?2 )", nativeQuery = true)
    List<User> getMatches(String userId, int matchingTracks);

}
```

Main class:

```java
package perosnal.tunelink;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ImportAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.EnableFeignClients;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignAutoConfiguration;

@EnableFeignClients
@ImportAutoConfiguration({FeignAutoConfiguration.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Config only contains 1 file that allows all origins for CORS.

Project structure:

[image: structure]

Error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personal.tunelink.user.UserRepositoryITest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository': No qualifying bean of type 'perosnal.tunelink.user.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: What does your config look like? Maybe you need to make a bean with useRepository

Comment: or you don't have the proper annotations on the userRepository class

Comment: @devin I edited the question and added my repository

Comment: What does your runner look like? or your config?

Comment: do you have something called @ComponentScan anywhere in your app(usually in the main entry point) . Show me this if not I would add @ComponentScan("com.packagename");

Comment: What scares me in your structure is your `config` package, what does it contain? What does your `Application` class look like. You don't need the `spring-boot-starter` dependencies (that is implied by the others), remove the version from the `spring-boot-starter-validation` dependency. The `@Repository` on the `UserRepository` only adds clutter. And I suspect your open feign dependency isn't compatible with Spring Boot 3 (and pulling in older/conflicting dependencies).

Comment: I edited the question and added my main class, tried bumping up feign dependency version to 4.0.1 but still same error. My config dir only contains one file that simply allows all origins for CORS. I don't have ComponentScan anywhere and I tried adding scanBasePackages = {"personal.tunelink"} to SpringBootApplication but issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your application.java class.

```
@ComponentScan({"personal.tunelink.*"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

also you have mispelled the package name in your repository class, as well as your application class please correct this:

```
package perosnal.tunelink.user;
```

I believe you mean it to be this:

```
package personal.tunelink.user
```

Comment: Fixing the package class names might be enough but the personal.tunelink component scan should definitely fix your issue. Please let me know if this worked by upvoting and marking my answer as correct.

Comment: If you need further help I will need to see the repository for this project